# Bootstrap style form inline

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to make my form in this style as image reference i tried but i did not get success
[image]

I  made the structure as following code ... if there is someone have any other code reference to share will be good too. thanks

link [demo](http://www.bootply.com/9QEG6hU5rp#)

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col col-sm-12">
                <div class="container"><br/>
                    <form class="form form-inline form-multiline" role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Filtros">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-sm-12">
                            <div class="col col-sm-4">
                                <ul>
                                    <h4>Situação</h4>
                                    <li>Útumos incluídos</li>
                                    <li>Todos</li>
                                    <li>Ativos</li>
                                    <li>Excluídos</li>
                                    <li>Inativos</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col col-sm-4">
                                <ul>
                                    <h4>Tipo de cadastro</h4>
                                    <li>Cliente</li>
                                    <li>Fornecedor</li>
                                    <li>Transportador</li>
                                    <li>Vendedor</li>
                                    <li>Sem tipo definido</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col col-sm-4">
                                <h4>Outras opções de pesquisa</h4>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Vendedor</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label>Município</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <label>Estado</label><br/>
                                                <select name="" id="">
                                                    <option value=""></option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Telefone / Celular</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Prox. Visita</lebel>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <label>De:</label>
                                                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <label>Até:</label>
                                                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Sem compras no período:</lebel>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <label>De:</label>
                                                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <label>Até:</label>
                                                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the combination of [Bootstrap Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), `col-*-*`, and use it with your `.form-group` classes.

Have a look at the snippet below (*use full screen mode*) or look at the updated **[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/Qg3tgeR7x6)**.

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}

.form-control {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.input-group {
  width: 100%;
}

.form-holder {
  margin: 0 -15px;
}

.form-holder h4 {
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col col-sm-12">
  <div class="container"><br>
   <form class="form form-inline form-multiline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Filtros">
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-12">
     <div class="col col-sm-4">
      <ul>
       <h4>Situação</h4>
       <li>Útumos incluídos</li>
       <li>Todos</li>
       <li>Ativos</li>
       <li>Excluídos</li>
       <li>Inativos</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="col col-sm-4">
      <ul>
       <h4>Tipo de cadastro</h4>
       <li>Cliente</li>
       <li>Fornecedor</li>
       <li>Transportador</li>
       <li>Vendedor</li>
       <li>Sem tipo definido</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="col col-sm-4">
      <h4>Outras opções de pesquisa</h4>
      <div class="form-holder">
       <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <label>Vendedor</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
        <label>Município</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
        <label>Estado</label>
        <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
         <option value="">Select</option>
        </select>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <label>Telefone / Celular</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
       </div>
       <h4>Prox. Visita</h4>
       <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label>De:</label>
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
         <input type="text" class="form-control">
         <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
         </span>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label>Até:</label>
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
         <input type="text" class="form-control">
         <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
         </span>
        </div>
       </div>
       <h4>Sem compras no período</h4>
       <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
       <label>De:</label>
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
         <input type="text" class="form-control">
         <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
         </span>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label>Até:</label>
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
         <input type="text" class="form-control">
         <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
         </span>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @MinaMagdy Hope my answer helped you out, if yes don't forget to upvote & accept. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

used:

```
[class*='col-sm-']:not(:last-child):after
```